# Can not clean up outliers with own function in R

Tags: r, function, outliers

I'm trying to write a simple function to clean up the data from outliers.
The function is as follows:

```
replaceOutliers <- function(data){
    Q1 <- quantile(data,0.25)
    Q3 <- quantile(data,0.75)
    IQR <- Q3 - Q1
    upperWhisker <- Q3 + 1.5*IQR
    lowerWhisker <- Q1 - 1.5*IQR

    data[data > upperWhisker] <- upperWhisker
    data[data < lowerWhisker] <- lowerWhisker
    return (data)
}
```

Than I copy it to the console and call with replaceOutliers(CIR_WORK$Mean.RED) statement. But nothing's happens. The CIR_WORK$Mean.RED remains untouched.
I suppose the steps of function are correct because when I perform it one by one in console the result is as I want to. But not with the function. Anybody knows why?

Cheers

Comment: Did you do `CIR_WORK$Mean.RED <- replaceOutliers(CIR_WORK$Mean.RED)`, i.e. have you assigned the result to the original variable?

Comment: It looks like you are replacing the outliers. Why not delete them???

Comment: Marichyasana - it is because I have to keep the primary length of data.